# Using variable in a name of uploaded file in Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm pushing a file to my FTP, and I have

```
file = open(home_path + '\\Desktop\\' + checkuser + ' Report.txt', 'rb')
session.storbinary('STOR file.txt', file)
```

This I believe copies the content from the file on my Desktop and creates a file `file.txt` on the FTP;

I can't seem to be able to create a file name on the FTP that is the same as the one on my Desktop
(or any desktop/user), something like

```
session.storbinary('STOR' + home_path + '\\Desktop\\' + checkuser + ' Report.txt', file)
```

Is there a way around this?

*PS: running

```
sys.stdout = open(home_path + '\\Desktop\\' + checkuser + ' Report.txt', 'a')
```

works just fine, it creates a file named *currentuser* Report.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you problem. But maybe you want to do this?

```
session.storbinary('STOR ' + checkuser + ' Report.txt', file)
```

(assuming the `checkuser` value is a part of the filename)

And note the space after `STOR` (which is missing in your code).